# Target Action for lazy Button does not work

Tags: swift, uibutton, lazy-loading, target-action

Using Swift 5.1.3, iOS13.3, XCode11.3,

I try to create a simple Button Target Action.

However, the Button is inside its own StackView class and moreover, is a lazy button.

Why is the Target Action not working in my Code ? i.e. `callButtonMethod` is never called !

Could it be because of the late API responses or is it because a lazy button cannot do target action. I am clueless at the moment.

Thank you for any help on this.

Here is my code:

```
class CockpitHeaderStackView: UIStackView {

    weak var profileBtnDelegate: CallButtonProfileImage?

    var profileImageView = UIImageView()
    var profileName = "Cockpit".localized

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {

        if let profile = MyAPI.profile, let person = profile.person {
            profileName = "\(person.firstName ?? "") \(person.lastName ?? "")"
        }

        MyAPI.getPicture(PictureType.avatar) { [weak self] (error, image) in

            guard let self = self else { return } // check if self still alive otherwise bail out

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let image = image {
                    self.profileImageView.image = image
                } else {
                    self.profileImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile-placeholder-small")
                }
                self.profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

                self.axis = .horizontal
                self.alignment = .bottom
                self.spacing = 10.0
                self.addArrangedSubview(self.titleLabel)
                self.addArrangedSubview(self.button)
            }
        }
    }

    lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let labelWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16.0 - 10.0 - 36.0 - 16.0   // FullScreenWidth minus (Leading + Spacing + ButtonWidth + Trailing)
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = AppConstants.Font.NavBar_TitleFont
        label.text = profileName
        label.textColor = .white
        label.tintColor = .white
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelWidth).isActive = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    lazy var button: UIButton = {

        let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 36.0
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)))

        button.setImage(self.profileImageView.image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callButtonMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 36)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
        button.layer.masksToBounds = false
        button.clipsToBounds = true

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true

        return button
    }()

    @objc func callButtonMethod() {
        profileBtnDelegate?.callProfileBtnMethod()
    }
}
```

The `CockpitHeaderStackView` is used to create a custom NavigationBar of my ViewController.

Here the code for the custom NavigationBar with usage of the `CockpitHeaderStackView` :

```
protocol CallButtonProfileImage: AnyObject {
    func callProfileBtnMethod()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    lazy var titleStackView: CockpitHeaderStackView = {
        let titleStackView = CockpitHeaderStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 88.0)))
        titleStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return titleStackView
    }()

    lazy var cockpitHeaderView: UIView = {
        let cockpitHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 88.0)))
        cockpitHeaderView.addSubview(titleStackView)
        titleStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        titleStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
        titleStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        return cockpitHeaderView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...

        view.clipsToBounds = true

        navigationController?.set_iOS12_lookAndFeel()
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        // replace NavBar title by custom cockpitHeaderView
        self.title = ""
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.cockpitHeaderView
        // position the cockpitHeaderView inside the largeTitleDisplayMode NavBar
        self.cockpitHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.cockpitHeaderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        if let navBarBottomAnchor = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > 568.0 {
                self.cockpitHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBarBottomAnchor, constant: -48.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                self.cockpitHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBarBottomAnchor, constant: -46.0).isActive = true  // iPhone SE space limitation
            }
        } else {
            self.cockpitHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 89.0).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func callProfileBtnMethod() {
        print("right BarButton called here")
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should set in your init ```userInterectionEnabled = true```

Comment: Is your delegate set properly? I guess your button method gets called, but your delegate not. Test your callButtonMethod with a simple print statement

Comment: @A.Amini: Hm, nope, this does not help. I tried adding `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on the lazy-button, on the self.button inside the API-callback and also on the stackView itself. But no help. The target-action still does not kick-in.... Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @Chris: No - not even the `@objc func callButtonMethod() { ... }` action gets called. That is what is most puzzling to me also !

Comment: @ikk Not inside lazy Button declaration, buttons are always enabled to interact with the user. Try to set this inside your commonInit() for your stackView.

Comment: @A.Amini:  I just did place the `self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.callButtonMethod), for: .touchUpInside)` inside the `commonInit()` - more precisely inside the DispatchQueue right before the two `self.addArrangedSubView(...)`.  And also `self.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` But no luck - again not working target-action. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @iKK no  write ```self. isUserInteractionEnabled = true``` inside commonInit

Comment: @A.Amini: I did that too - but no luck :(.  Let me check at the location where the stackView is placed. // I did check and there the StackView is just added as a subview to a ViewController's View. Nothing special and shouldn't prevent the userInteraction, I think.

Comment: is your button visible ?

Comment: button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.callButtonMethod), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: try out this line and let me know if it solve your issue

Comment: @iKK what exactly are you trying to click? `titleLabel` or `button`? I ran your code and `callButtonMethod` is called just fine when I click `button`

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath: I am trying to click button. But when I klick the button, it does not work. I will place the rest of the code (i.e. precisely where the StackView is used) into the original question. Maybe the fact that the StackView is used inside a custom NavBar HeaderView is maybe the root cause of my issue. Please consult the original question again with the added custom NavigationBar.

Comment: @jawadAli: sorry my late answer - I was in the bus :). To answer your questions: Yes, the button is visible (as expected inside the custom NavBar using the StackView at question). And yes, I did place your line-suggestion (as well inside the API-callback in the lazy button using `self.button.addTarget(...)` as well as inside `commonInit()`. But both trials without success - still no target-action working in my iPhone 11 Pro Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found "a solution":  The lazy initialisations seem to be the cause of the error-behaviour.

In fact, when I replace all lazy initialisation and also eliminate the StackView (called `CockpitHeaderStackView`) and put everything in non-lazy let-constants, then it works !!

Here is the final and relevant code (i.e. I placed everything inside the `viewWillAppear`method):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let cardsHorizontalController = CardsHorizontalController()
    self.view.addSubview(cardsHorizontalController.view)
    cardsHorizontalController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cardsHorizontalController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0).isActive = true
    cardsHorizontalController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 279).isActive = true
    cardsHorizontalController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true

    navigationController?.set_iOS12_lookAndFeel()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

    PeaxAPI.getPicture(PictureType.avatar) { [weak self] (error, image) in

        guard let self = self else { return } // check if self still alive otherwise bail out

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let image = image {
                self.profileImageView.image = image
            } else {
                self.profileImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile-placeholder-small")
            }
            self.profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

            if let profile = PeaxAPI.profile, let person = profile.person {
                self.profileName = "\(person.firstName ?? "") \(person.lastName ?? "")"
            }

            let titleStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 88.0)))
            titleStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            titleStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            titleStackView.axis = .horizontal
            titleStackView.alignment = .bottom
            titleStackView.spacing = 10.0

            let labelWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16.0 - 10.0 - 36.0 - 16.0   // FullScreenWidth minus (Leading + Spacing + ButtonWidth + Trailing)
            let label = UILabel()
            label.font = AppConstants.Font.NavBar_TitleFont
            label.text = self.profileName
            label.textColor = .white
            label.tintColor = .white
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelWidth).isActive = true
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 36.0
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)))

            button.setImage(self.profileImageView.image, for: .normal)
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.callProfileBtnMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 36)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
            button.layer.masksToBounds = false
            button.clipsToBounds = true

            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true

            titleStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            titleStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)

            let cockpitHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 88.0)))
            cockpitHeaderView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cockpitHeaderView.addSubview(titleStackView)
            titleStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
            titleStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            titleStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
            titleStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cockpitHeaderView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

            // replace NavBar title by custom cockpitHeaderView
            self.title = ""
            self.navigationItem.titleView = cockpitHeaderView
            cockpitHeaderView.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add addTarget after adding the button as a subview and that worked